# Laravel 4 - Print out a table and its associated categories

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to print out all book names and its associated category in 'books' table and 'book_categories' table.

But I'm getting this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: books.blade.php)

The name of my two table models:

> - Book.php
> - BookCategory.php

My 'books' table stucture:

> id(int), book_name(string), book_category_id(int)

My 'book_categories' table structure:

> id(int), book_category(string)

Controller:

```
public function getBooks(){

  $books = Book::all();

  return View.make('book.books')->with('books', $books);
}
```

books.blade.php

```
@foreach ($books as $book)
<p>{{ $book->book_name }} </p>
<p>{{ BookCategory::find($book->id)->book_category }}</p>
@endforeach
```

It prints out JSON information correctly when just this line of code: `BookCategory::find($book-id)`

But when I use

> ->first()

or

> ->book_category

to access its content it's not working.

Comment: did you establish the relationship in your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Books extends \Model {

    $table = 'books';

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('BookCategory');
    }
}

class BookCategory extends \Model {

    $table = 'book_categories';

    public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Books', 'book_category_id');
    }
}

public function getBooks() 
{
    // Always eagerload your relation to prevent n+1 issue
    $books = Books::with('categories')->all();

    return View::make('book.books')->with('books', $books);
}

@foreach($books as $book)
    {{ $book->book_name}}
    {{ $book->categories->book_category }}
@endforeach
```

Further Reading:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations
http://daylerees.com/codebright/eloquent-relationships